# Bubble Sort: How to prevent it from comparing to itself in the first iteration

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

As you can see the code below compares to itself in the first iteration and is a waste of process. But the solution I'm thinking of would most likely go `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, I would need some help solving this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            int result = words[i].compareTo(words[j]);
            if (result < 0) {
                String temp;
                temp = words[i];
                words[i] = words[j];
                words[j] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about `if (i!=j) {...}`?

Comment: What solution are you thinking of?

Comment: Also, to be clear, this implementation doesn't work...

Comment: I was thinking of j=1 then j<words.length-1. But that would go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest `int j = i + 1`, also `i < words.length - 1` like

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
        // Nothing changed below this line...
        int result = words[i].compareTo(words[j]);
        if (result > 0) {
            T temp = words[i];
            words[i] = words[j];
            words[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```